# opencv remove noise / detect net with canny

Tags: python, opencv

What would be your approach to detecting the volleyball net on this images.
Unfortunately, `bilateralFilter` or `gaussianBlur` all result in a lot of noise (especially the trees and sand) for the `canny` line detector.

Can you suggest a better course of action ?

**Pic1:**

[image]

**Pic2:**

[image]

Comment: more preprocessing is needed before canny. you can try to extract x and y derivatives with sobel operator.

Comment: The comment above is right, although your image there is in a  projective space, your net edges are almost rectangular, so if you apply sobel x derivator and y derivator, you will remove most of sand and three noise. Here a Opencv Sobel Ref python http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_gradients/py_gradients.html, C++ http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html

Comment: are you processing single images or videos? Will camera be stationary for a single video?

Comment: @Micka In fact, I'm processing a video and camera will be stable for the duration of the video. The net has no movement during the video and neither the trees or the sand